# Passport authentication missing credentials in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am learning how to implement user authentication using [passport.js](https://www.passportjs.org/). I have a basic passport "local" strategy set up on the server side and so far just a single POST route to log a user in. This all works exactly as intended when troubleshooting with [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/products/insomnia) but when I make the same request from the browser I get a message `missing credentials`. This message is coming from `console.log(info)` in controllers/auth.js.

I have tried including credentials in the fetch request as seen below but I must be missing something else or including them incorrectly. I have also changed the variable names from 'email' to 'username' since I read that was the default for passport.js.

From what I can tell in Chrome dev tools, the request body is formatted correctly and I am hitting the proper endpoint.

**controllers/auth.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");

router.post("/register_login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
        console.log(info)
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: err });
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: "No user found" });
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({ errors: err });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ success: `logged in ${user.id}` });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**passport/setup.js**

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { User } = require('../models');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// Local Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
        // Match User
        User.findOne({ email: username })
            .then(user => {
                // Create new User
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'No user found!!'})
                    // Return other user
                } else {
                    // Match password
                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        if (isMatch) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password' });
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return done(null, false, { message: err });
            });
    })
);

module.exports = passport;
```

**client side fetch**

```js
const handleLogin = async (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('/auth/register_login', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        withCredentials: true,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": "test@email.com",
            "password": "password"
        })
    })
    return response;
};
```

Comment: You might just replace "username" to "usernameField" and "password" to "passwordField" in you fetch request.

Comment: @Dipak I have updated the variables in my fetch as such, `{ "usernameField": "test@email.com", "passwordField": "password" }` and still get the same results as before.

Comment: A quick update: I added `console.log(req.body)` in the POST route and that is empty in the browser and as expected in Insomnia. So that is definitely my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oof, that was a simple one...

I was reading the "Content-Type" in Chrome dev tools however I was reading the "Response Headers" thinking they were the "Request Headers". The issue is that I was sending text instead of json.

Changing the client side fetch to the snippet below resolved the issue.

**client side fetch**

```js
const handleLogin = async (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('/auth/register_login', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' // <--add this
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": "test@email.com",
            "password": "password"
        })
    })
    return response;
};
```